# Why is my Java string converter not working?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

My task is to reverse a string. I am doing it by converting the string to a char array. Then pushing and poping the characters to/from a stack to a char array. Then I convert the char array back to string. Here is my code:

```
public class StringReverser {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String convertThis = "hej";
    //print out char pre convert
    System.out.println(convertThis);

    //convert here
    StringReverser strrvs = new StringReverser();
    String newConvert = strrvs.convertString(convertThis);
    //print out char post convert
    System.out.println(newConvert);
}

public String convertString (String string){


    //convert string to char array
    char[] charToConvert = string.toCharArray();
    //get number of characters
    int s = charToConvert.length;
    //create a stack
    MyStack mystack = new MyStack(s);
    //push all character in character list on stack.
    for(char character : charToConvert){
        mystack.push(character);
    }
    //get all character from stack. they are now in reversed order
    int charnumb = 0;
    while(mystack.isEmpty() != false){
        charToConvert[charnumb] = mystack.pop();
        charnumb++;
    }
    //convert character array to string
    String newString = String.valueOf(charToConvert);
    return newString;

}

private class MyStack{

    //variables for size of stack size
    private int stackSize;
    private char[] stackArray;
    private int top;

    //create the stack
    public MyStack(int s) {

        stackSize = s;
        stackArray = new char[stackSize];
        top = -1;

    }

    //method for pushing character on top of stack.
    public void push(char push) {
        stackArray[++top] = push;
    }
    //method for pop the character on top of stack.
    public char pop() {
        return stackArray[top--];
    }
    //method for getting the character on top of stack.
    public long peek() {
        return stackArray[top];
    }
    //method for checking if stack is empty.
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (top == -1);
    }
    //method for checking if stack is full.
    public boolean isFull() {
        return (top == stackSize - 1);
    }


}
```

}

Comment: "Not working" is a very broad term. What goes wrong exactly?

Comment: @ILoveCoding I suppose I should have explained my problem better. My code did not return a reversed string, instead it did return the same string that I wanted to convert. But someone explained to me that there was a error in my while loop and it is now fixed. Thank you for reminding me about not explaining my problem enough, I will take it to consideration next time I post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while(mystack.isEmpty() != false)` is equivalent to `while (mystack.isEmpty)`, which means your loop will exit immediately without popping anything from the stack.

You should change it to :

```
while(!mystack.isEmpty()){
    charToConvert[charnumb] = mystack.pop();
    charnumb++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just a `StringBuilder` to reverse your String.

```
new StringBuilder("AwesomeString").reverse().toString()
```

Comment: Thanks. I know I can do that, but my task was to reverse a String without using StringBuilder. But that do work.